# "There are scientists out there actively looking for solutions." What is the function of "....out there..." in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

This is from the BBC Earth Lab [Super volcanoes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDHAmo0n_Eg) (see:9:50-9:55)

**"It is, however, reassuring to know that there are scientists out there actively looking for solutions."**

I think the **"....out there..."** in the sentence does not seem to add anything to the meaning of the sentence, because the sentence can have completely the same meaning even when you remove it. Let's see the sentence without **"...out there.."**?

**"It is, however, reassuring to know that there are scientists actively looking for solutions."**

So, why is there an **"....out there...."**?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, yes it answes my question.